# can't run recorded espresso test in androidstudio

Tags: android-studio, testing, gradle, android-espresso

I runned a "record espresso test" in android studio.
I clicked my stuff and saved. The gui asked me to add missing dependencies in gradle for using specific libraries. Of course I allowed and I can see the new dependencies:

```
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
}
```

but my testclass is red and I can't start it.

[image]

What is the trick to add the correct dependencies ?
Can someone help ?

**UPDATE**
When switching to build variant debug. The missing classes problem is solved. I do not understand. I have no build variant "debug" configured and why doe it work with it. Totally confusing all. Can someone help ?

Comment: Have you been able to solve this problem? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

You can click Option+Return key on any of the red lines from the above screenshot on a Mac, and you will see an option to add the concerning library. I don't know what the equivalent shortcut is on Windows or Linux, though. Also, once you are done adding any libraries to your gradle file, then do a gradle sync (pretty sure you already know this).

Comment: I guess thats not that easy. This doesn't solve my issue. Shortcut would be Alt-Enter (or just clicking on the red Icon, which can't be overseen.) , but its not the solution :-)